# How to invalidate Dockerfile cache when pip installing from repo

Tags: python, git, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that needs to install the latest package code from a private git repo, however because the dockerfile/url/commit doesn't change (I just follow the latest in master), Docker will cache this request and won't pull the latest code.

I can disable build caching entirely which fixes the issue - but this results in a slow build.

How can I just force docker not to use the cache for the one command?

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

COPY ./requirements.txt /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# This needs to be separate to trigger to invalidate the build cache
RUN pip install -e git+https://TOKEN@github.com/user/private-package.git#egg=private_package

COPY ./main.py /app
COPY ./app /app/app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
ARG foo=bar
```

Before  `RUN pip install -e ...` in your docker file.
Then in your script with `docker build ....`  add as a parameter
`--build-arg foo="$(date -s)"`

Comment: This response is impossible to understand.